# What secrets need to provide to connect to sstp vpn

Tags: linux, vpn, manjaro, networkmanager

I am trying to connect to SSTP VPN but get next error:

```
Necessary secrets for the VPN connection 'VPN_NAME' were not provided.
```

In journalctl there`s error:

```
[1651404679.1287] vpn[0x5642718fc5f0,9d81d1cf-d8ca-48c8-8be7-556901c62a20,"myvpnconnection"]: plugin NeedSecrets request #1 (closed) failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Error.BadArguments: Invalid connection type.
```

What secrets need to provide to connect to Vpn?

#### network-manager-sstp information

```
Name            : network-manager-sstp
Version         : 1.3.0-1
Description     : SSTP support for NetworkManager
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/network-manager-sstp
Licenses        : GPL2
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : gtk3  libnma  libsecret  sstp-client
Optional Deps   : ppp [installed]
Required By     : None
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 689,00 KiB
Packager        : Felix Yan <felixonmars@archlinux.org>
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
Backup Files    :
```

## RESOLVE

```
nmcli connection modify <your vpn connection name> +vpn.data "connection-type = password"
```

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/